# so im making an virtual assistant on python

Tags: python

so the virtual assistant works but when I say something it doesn't listen or respond

```
listening...
recognizing...
network connection issue...
```

it just keeps printing this☝

here is the code that I have written fr making it

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import wikipedia
import datetime
import pyttsx3
import webbrowser
import random
import os
import pyaudio

#text to speech

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
print(voices)

#print(voices)

engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)

def speak(audio): #here audio is var which contain text
engine.say(audio)
engine.runAndWait()

def wish():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        speak("good morning, i am your virtual assistant")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("good afternoon, i am your virtual assistant")
    else:
        speak("hello, i am your virtual assistant")

#now convert audio to text

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("recognizing...")
        speak("recognising")
        query = r.recognition_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user said:{query}\n")

    except Exception:
        speak("error...")
        print("network connection issue...")     #for error handling
        return "none"
    return query

#for the main function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wish()
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()

        if "wikipedia" in query:
            speak("searching details...")
            query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences = 2)
            print(results)
            speak(results)

        elif "open youtube" in query or "youtube" in query:
            speak("opening youtube")
            webbrowser.open("www.youtube.com")

        elif "open google" in query or "google" in query:
            speak("opening google")
            webbrowser.open("www.google.co.in")

        elif "music from laptop" in query or "music" in query:
            speak("ok playing music")
            music_dir = "./music"
            musics = os.listdir(music.dir)
            os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, music[0]))

        elif "music from laptop" in query or "music" in query:
            speak("ok playing music")
            music_dir = "./video"
            musics = os.listdir(music.dir)
            os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, video[0]))

        elif "good bye" in query:
            speak("good bye")
            exit()

        elif "shutdown" in query:
            speak("shutting down")
            os.system('shutdown -s')
```

so after running it says the stuff it needs to it also prints the stuff it needs to but when it comes to listening to what the user is telling it just doesnt repond's and continues with the printing of
listening...
recognizing...
network connection issue...

Comment: It looks like you are missing some tags on your question. Perhaps, there are some that you can add to your question so it draws more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct! In function speak() there is indentation error I guess.

Did you try saying the commands while on an internet connection?

Comment: no i dint im new to these modules so can u tell the commands for the internet connection thing

Comment: Internet connection means to connect your PC to the internet while saying/giving commands since ```r.recognize_google``` uses the google API, just the same thing that your google assistant in android uses for speech recognition.

Comment: oh yea that thing works and thanx for your effort and my code works now

Answer (score 0):

1. There is an indentation error in your `speak()` function.
2. In your `takeCommand()` function it should be `r.recognize_google` instead of `r.recognition_google`.

Edit:

3. I've never tried so I don't know.
4. Add:

```
    elif "search on google" in query:
                speak("searching on google")
                line = query.strip("search on google ")
                webbrowser.open("www.google.co.in"+"/search?q="+line)
```

And make sure to remove `or "google" in query` in the open google elif or change the whole thing with:

```
elif "google" in query and "search" not in query:
            speak("opening google")
            webbrowser.open("www.google.co.in")
```

Comment: oh the indentation thing isn't there in the code it might have come while I was copy-pasting the code over here

Comment: omg thank you so much i dint see the recognizing thing and it works now but I still have one doubt why isint the goodbye command not working??

Comment: Use `'goodbye'` without spaces in the second-last elif.

Comment: and also do you know any command that i can add in the code wher i say it to increase brightness and it increases the brightness of my laptop..

Comment: and is there any way you can make the thing get results directly from google for a separate query

Comment: Editing my answer.